# The method valueOf(Object) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: jsp

Im getting the following error:
The method valueOf(Object) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (void)  <%=loadProductListView("men","shirt")  %>

In javascript Im calling loadProductListView method:

```
                   <script>
                   $(document).ready(function () {
                   $("#idMenShirts").click(function () {
                  $("#idListView").html('');
                 <%=loadProductListView("men","shirt")  %>
                  });
                 </script>
```

Here I have declared loadProductListView

```
                       <%!
                   public static void  loadProductListView(String cat,String 
                                                                      type) 
                       {    
                           %>  
                    <sql:setDataSource var = "snapshot" driver = 
                   "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                     url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
                   user = "system" password = "1234" />
                 System.out.println("connected for products");
                 <c:set var = "cat" value = "$(cat)"/>
                   <c:set var = "type" value = "$(type)"/>
                      <sql:query dataSource = "${snapshot}" var = "result">
                       SELECT product_name,product_desc,image_desc FROM 
                      products WHERE product_category= ? and product_type= 
                                                                        ?; 

        <sql:param value="${cat}" />
        <sql:param value="${type}" />
        </sql:query>
        <script>
         <c:forEach var = "row" items = "${result.rows}">  

          var img= <c:out value = "${row.image_desc}"/> +".jpg";
          var name=<c:out value = "${row.product_name}"/>;
          var desc=<c:out value = "${row.product_desc}"/>;
          var pro_desc=<c:out value = "${row.image_desc}"/>+".jsp";





 $("#one ul").append('<li class="ui-li-has-thumb"><a href="'+pro_desc+'" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">' +
                    '<img src="img/' + img + '" style="height: 80px;width: 80px;"/>' +
                    '<h2>' + name + '</h2>' +
                    '<p>' + desc + '</p>' +
                    '</a>' +
                    '</li >');


    $('#one ul').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print the result returned by the method `loadProductListView()`. But this method returns void. So that doesn't make sense.

I have no idea what you actually want to achieve because your code is unindented and is a spaghetti of intermingled HTML, JavaScript, JSPL tags and scriptlets, so all I can say is that you're doing it wrong

- don't use scriptlets
- don't use sql tags. They're officially documented as a quick and dirty hack
- put your logic (database access, parameter handling etc.) in controllers written as Java classes, invoked from a servlet, and use JSP, with JSTL, custom tags, but no single scriptlet, exclusively to generate HTML from beans stored in the request by the controller.

There are plenty of framework helping architecturing your app in the right way (and more). Pick one of them and use it.